# Cannot update some systemuser in dataverse - Email address not approved error message

Tags: c#, dataverse

We're trying to update user information in systemuser table of a Dataverse environmment and we get error message for many users. We're using Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client and Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.

I'm updating only 2 fields I don't know if that help: businessunitid and employeeid.

ErrorCode: 0x8009000B
Message: Email address can only be approved by an Office 365 Global Administrator or by an Exchange Administrator. For more information, contact your system administrator.

Anyone got this situation? How can I resolve it? By the way we do not use Dynamic 365 / Dataverse to send any email.